# ActionScript 3 - Adding a new instance of a symbol

Tags: actionscript-3

I feel so ridiculous. I've been trying to do this for 20 minutes and have been looking at other websites and they just aren't giving me consistent answers. Some are saying do this, some are saying do that.

Anyway, how would I add a new instance of a movie clip called "bird" to the stage?

Answer (score 0):

> how would I add a new instance of a movie clip called "bird" to the stage?

```
stage.addChild(new bird());
```

I assume you didn't forget to set up `Export for ActionScript` ; )